# Can Shelly Pro 4PM or SONOFF 4CHR3 Handle High Starting Currents of Water Circulation Pumps?

Tags: relay, home-automation

I’m interested in automating my heating system, which currently relies on four water circulating pumps (one for the buffer tank, one for the heat tank, and two for different sections of the house). My goal is to control the operation of these water circulation pumps based on either the temperature of the buffer tank or the time of day.

The power ratings of these water circulation pumps range from 60 to 200 watts. I’ve been researching smart relay options like the Shelly Pro 4PM and the SONOFF 4CHR3. While both of these devices can handle the power requirements, I have concerns about the peak current that occurs when the pumps are turned on.

Does anyone foresee any issues with using such a smart relay in this setup? Can these devices handle the high starting current of the circulation pumps? If they can’t, are there any solutions you could suggest?

Comment: Please ask the manufacturer about the specs what it can handle. But for that you would need to provide the specs for starting current profile of the motors so you need motor specs too.